# How can I use angular ui-select' selected item with VALUE and TEXT

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select2, ui-select

I have a list of countries which were loaded into
[angular ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/Roadmap)

Detail of code is as below

```
%ui-select{'ng-model' => 'item.country', 'append-to-body' => 'true', 'search-enable' => 'true', 'them' => 'bootstrap'}
                %ui-select-match{'allow-clear' => 'true', placeholder: :'select country'}{{$select.selected.name}}
                %ui-select-choices{'repeat' => "country.code as country in countries | filter:$select.search"}
                  %span {{country.name}}
```

Every object country have 2 properties are CODE and NAME
when i selected an item the value and displayed text are always NAME

My expected is when selecting an item the value is CODE and the displayed text is NAME. 
`%ui-select-choices` element can become
like this:

```
%option{'ng-repeat' => "country in countries", 'value' => '{{country.code}}', 'text' => '{{country.name}}'}
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try
          country.code as country.name for country in countries

Comment: if we use the expression country.code as country.name for country in countries in repeat error will occur. This expression is fine for ng-option